# How to use BS_SPLITBUTTON in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu but i cannot find any documentation neither on MSDN.

```
edit = CreateWindow("Button", "1h2f3d4", WS_BORDER |WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_SPLITBUTTON, 5, 30, 23, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_EDIT, NULL, NULL);
```

it works, but it doesn't show anything in the button

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to send the [BCM_SETSPLITINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the newly created button with a pointer to a [BUTTON_SPLITINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. That should fill in what is missing.

Some pseudocode:

```
BUTTON_SPLITINFO MyInfo;
MyInfo.mask = BCSIF_STYLE | BCSIF_GLYPH;
MyInfo.uSplitStyle = BCSS_STRETCH;
MyInfo.himlGlyph = [A Glyph from an Image List]
Button_SetSplitInfo(edit, &MyInfo); // Send the BCM_SETSPLITINFO message to the control.
```

You would still have to provide the image list and the glyph to display.

Comment: i don't know why, but it tells me "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".

Comment: @DomeWTF Well, double check you are including Commctrl.h and have your windows versions set correctly.

Comment: i included this
    #include<Commctrl.h>
    #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
to make it stop looking like a win 98 program, and yes, i have both Windows.h and Commctrl.h

Comment: what do you mean by "check if you have your windows versions set correctly"?

Comment: This should cover what you need to know to set the version for the header files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: it says on MSDN that BUTTON_SPLITINFO requires windows vista, and so i've put #define NTDDI_VISTA 0x06000000 but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @DomeWTF You don't redefine `NTDDI_VISTA`, you define `NTDDI_VERSION` to be `NTDDI_VISTA`. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/bb6ec83d-6711-4f5c-a1a4-6aeba1602c03)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the compiler use Common Controls version 6.0, in VC++ (Best I think in the very start of your project, in a .h file:)

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

I don't really know how to do it on other compilers like GCC, but placing a .manifest file with the same info next to your .exe file can also do the trick.